# struggling to understand the meaning of a sentence about joint distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,...X_n$ be random variables. What does "Let $P$ and $Q$ denote two joint distributions for $(X_1,...,X_n)$" mean ? How can $(X_1,...X_n)$ have more than one joint distribution ?
I know this may seem like a dumb question but I really don't get it

Comment: In what context did that come up? Maybe in a problem asking to show that there is only one joint distribution?

Comment: this comes from an exercise about the kullback-leibler divergence in the book "Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence". Here is a screenshot of the full statement : https://ibb.co/ZY5tTgW